# What's the difference between "deletemany" and "remove" in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

What's the difference between the two commands here?
`db.collection.deleteMany({condition})`
`db.collection.remove({condition})`

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

Try this it may help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As far as I can say,

> db.collection.deleteMany

```
Returns:    
   A document containing:
       > A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was disabled
       > deletedCount containing the number of deleted documents
```

REF: [db.collection.deleteMany](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/)

Where as

> db.collection.remove

return [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#writeresults-remove)

And to remove a single document, there a similar command, `db.collection.removeOne` where as with `db.collection.remove` you need to set and option called `justOne` option to limit delete to 1 document.

Otherwise I guess they are similar.

> node.js drivers

When talking about `node.js drivers`, `remove` has been deprecated (and may be removed in future releases) and `deleteOne` or `deleteMany`.

Hope this makes sense ....

Answer (score 56):

They do the same. The difference is the **values** that **return**.

With `remove()`:

```
> db.ticker.remove({"name": "Bitcoin"})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 2 })
```

With `deleteMany()`:

```
> db.ticker.deleteMany({"name": "Bitcoin"})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 2 }
```